# How to properly implement single source project versioning in Python?

Tags: python, cmake, versioning

I love the way *CMake* allows me to single source version my C/C++ projects, by letting me say:

```
project(Tutorial VERSION 1.0)
```

in my `CMakeLists.txt` file and, then, use placeholders of the form:

```c
#define ver_maj @Tutorial_VERSION_MAJOR@
#define ver_min @Tutorial_VERSION_MINOR@
```

in my `*.h.in` file, which, when run through `configure_file()`, becomes:

```c
#define ver_maj 1
#define ver_min 0
```

in my equivalent `*.h` file.
I'm then able to include that file anywhere I need access to my project version numbers.

This is decidedly different than the experience I have with Python projects.
In that case, I'm often rebuilding, because I forgot to sync. up the version numbers in my `pyproject.toml` and `<module>/__init__.py` files.

**What is the preferred way to achieve something similar to *CMake* style single source project versioning in a Python project?**

Comment: What build system are you using for Python? This is very build system specific, as they pretty much all expose different mechanisms for specifying/discovery the distribution version

Comment: Build tools may differ in how they *produce* the package, but the end result should conform to a standard format that can be queried using the [`importlib.metadata`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.metadata.html) module in the standard library.

Comment: @Brian61354270, I'm using `conda-build`.

Comment: @chepner, and is that library intended to support self-referencing queries? (Please, see my response to zaufi, below.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `__init__.py` you can set the `__version__` like this:

```
from importlib.metadata import version as _get_version

# Set PEP396 version attribute
__version__ = _get_version('<put-your-package-name-here>')
```

Or, if your package targeted older Python:

```py
import sys
if sys.version_info >= (3, 8):
    from importlib.metadata import version as _get_version
else:
    from importlib_metadata import version as _get_version

# …
```

and a package requirement:

```
importlib-metadata = {version = ">= 3.6", markers="python_version < '3.8'"}
```

(use the proper syntax for your build tool)

Also, there are some extensions for build tools (e.g., `setuptools-scm` or `hatch-vcs`) that allows avoiding setting explicit version in the `pyproject.toml` for the sake of e.g., `git`. So, the only source of version becomes VCS used.

Comment: Is this approach intended to work for self-referencing cases? That is, if I put the line `__version__ = _get_version('myproj')` in the `myproj/__init__.py` file, should that work, or will it fail due to the circular reference? (I'm trying it and it's failing.)

Comment: Why it should fail? `hatch-vcs` will set the metadata for the package at build-time and the given statement just gets it at run-time.

Comment: If you don't use `hatch-vcs` (or similar) it's just a run-time getting part that remains. Not a failure reason anyway.